# How do I preserve prexisting identifiers when geocoding a list of addresses in R?

Tags: r, geocoding

I'm currently working with an R script set up to use RDSTK, a wrapper for the Data Science Toolkit API based on [this](http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/developerdocs#setup), to geocode a list of addresses from a CSV.

The script appears to work, but the list of addresses has a preexisting unique identifier which isn't preserved in the process - the input file has two columns: *id*, and *address*. The id column, for the purposes of the geocoding process, is meaningless, but I'd like the output to retain it - that is, I'd like the output, which has three columns (address, long, and lat) to have four - id being the first.

The issue is that

1. The output is not in the same order as the input addresses, or doesn't appear to be, so I cannot simply tack on the column of addresses at the end, and
2. The output does not include nulls, so the two would not be the same number of rows in any case, even if it was the same order, and
3. I am not sure how to effectively tie the id column in such that it becomes a part of the geocoding process, which obviously would be the ideal solution.

Here is the script:

```
require("RDSTK")
library(httr)
library(rjson)
dff = read.csv("C:/Users/name/Documents/batchtestv2.csv")
data <- paste0("[",paste(paste0("\"",dff$address,"\""),collapse=","),"]")
url  <- "http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/street2coordinates"
response <- POST(url,body=data)
json     <- fromJSON(content(response,type="text"))
geocode  <- do.call(rbind,lapply(json, function(x) c(long=x$longitude,lat=x$latitude)))
geocode

write.csv(geocode, file = "C:/Users/name/Documents/geocodetest.csv")
```

And here is a sample of the output:

```
2633 Camino Ramon Suite 500 San Ramon California 94583 United States                                   -121.96208 37.77027
555 Lordship Boulevard  Stratford Connecticut 6615 United States                                        -73.14098 41.16542
500 West 13th Street  Fort Worth Texas 76102 United States                                              -97.33288 32.74782
50 North Laura Street Suite 2500 Jacksonville Florida 32202 United States                               -81.65923 30.32733
7781 South Little Egypt Road  Stanley North Carolina 28164 United States                                -81.00597 35.44482
```

Maybe the solution is extraordinarily simple and I'm just being dense - it's entirely possible (I don't have extensive experience with any particular language, so I sometimes miss obvious things) but I haven't been able to solve it.

Thanks in advance!